# How to handle v-if with the back button in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using routing with Vue.js and am trying to use v-if to conditional display 2 divs. The first div is a list of items. The second div is the details of an item. A good example of what I am trying to do would be something similar to Gmail. You have your list of emails and when you click the subject, you are taken to a page that shows the whole email.

I have this somewhat working using v-if. In my data, I have a variable called view. When the page loads, this value is set to 'list', which shows the list div. When someone clicks something in the list div, this value switches to 'details'. and the details div shows.

The problem that I am running into is if the user hits the back button in the browser, the view variable does not get updated. This seems like it is a common scenario, so I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

```
    <div id="app">
    {{ view }} //for debugging

    <div class="list" v-if="view === 'list'"> 
    <table>
        <tr v-for="item in list">
            <td><router-link v-on:click.native="doSomething" v-bind:to="'/items/' + item.id">{{ item.title }}</router-link></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="details" v-if="view === 'details'">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

Snippets from my Vue declaration.

```
           data: {
                view : "list"
            },

            doSomething: function () {
                    var app = this;
                    app.view = "details"; 
                }
```

Comment: I think approach is not good here.Since you are using the vue router, you should create 2 components - 1st component would handle the list of items, 2nd component would handle the single item info.When you initialize routes in router config you will attach those components for specific path and give them name option if it's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="app">
    {{ view }} //for debugging

    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

And then add two routes:

```
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'emails',
    component: Emails,
},
{
    path: '/login',
    name: 'email.show',
    component: EmailShow,
}
```

After that `Emails` component should handle logic of showing all emails and `EmailShow` should handle showing just one email